# Issue with defining functions in Python

Tags: python, function

```
def write(name, finalscore, totalquestions, score, file_Object):
    pickle.dump (str(name) + ' got ' + str(finalscore) + ' percent from ' + str(totalquestions) + ' question(s), this is ' + str(score) + ' out of ' + str(totalquestions) + '.') ,file_Object)
    return
```

What is wrong with this function, it comes up with a syntax error on the last bracket.

I have imported pickle and defined all the variables it is part of a maths quiz  and I am trying to write the results to a text file.

btw I am doing GCSE computing.

Comment: there is one ( missing in the beginning

Comment: Where is it specifically?

Comment: is it before the pickle.dump

Comment: Counting parentheses appears to be difficult...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without string concatenation the function gains in readability and you can find more easily any error. E.g:

```
def write(name, finalscore, totalquestions, score, file_Object):
    pickle.dump ("%s got %s percent from %s questions(s), this is %s out of %s." % (name, finalscore, totalquestions, score, totalquestions), file_Object)
    return
```

Maybe your function needs some more tuning... (returning None?)